Failed to create provisioning profile in XCODE for MAC
Issue details
I tried to solve this by turning off push notifications but unable to get the push notification turning off option
No profiles for 'com.rakibrahi.IntegrationApp' were found. Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.rakibrahi.IntegrationApp'.
I tried to configure this for running appium in mac os

did you add the iphone to list of devices on your developer account ?
